# The article THE - two different specifications?

Tags: articles

I like **the** streets of London!

Here are my questions.

1) Does it mean that I like **ALL** streets of London or only some of them or it can mean either ALL or SOME?
2) Is it correct to leave "the" out? - I like streets of London!

Comment: Depends. It can be interpreted to mean that you like London's streets in general.

Comment: The article is an identifier. The streets that I like are the ones in London.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could mean either "I like *all* the streets of London" or "I like the *typical* streets of London". Given that London has 60,000 streets, the second interpretation is much more likely here.

Hence it's ok to say:

> I like the streets of London, but not this one.

Or:

> I like the streets of London, but not the ones in Brixton.

Or:

> I like the streets of London, every single one.

But it would be ungrammatical to say:

> *I like the streets of London, but not many of them.

Regarding the second question: no, it is not grammatical to omit "the".

Comment: But you could easily omit the article if you rephrased it slightly: *I like London streets*.